# Formatting the first two rows of data retrieved from multiple worksheets in to a combined view worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that consists of 5 worksheets that contain data and a 6th worksheet with a button that when clicked retrieves the data from the other 5 sheets to provide a combined view.

The data in the other 5 sheets is slightly different from each other, except for a few common columns so, I have to show the data in the combined view as one under the other with the country in row 1 and the headings in row 2 in bold text if possible for the data retrieved in each sheet.

I am able to run the macro via button to retrieve the data but I am not able to pull all the data in as required but for some reason,  my code for setting the rows 1 and 2 for each sheet to bold is not working (code below shows me trying to get the first row to be set to bold).

One thing to keep in mind is that the amount of data on each sheet (the number of rows) may differ each time the macro is run.

Appreciate any help.

```
    Option Compare Text
    Sub OptionCompareText()
    End Sub

    Sub SearchMultipleSheets()
    Dim arr(999, 14) As Variant, r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, s As String
        With Sheets(1)
            's = Range("b10").Value
            .Range("a13").Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, UsedRange.Columns.Count).ClearContents
        End With

        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> Sheets(1).Name Then
            With ws
                For Each r In .Range("a1", .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If r.Value & r.Offset(0, 1).Value & r.Offset(0, 2).Value & r.Offset(0, 3).Value & r.Offset(0, 4).Value _
                & r.Offset(0, 5).Value & r.Offset(0, 6).Value & r.Offset(0, 7).Value & r.Offset(0, 8).Value _
                & r.Offset(0, 9).Value & r.Offset(0, 10).Value & r.Offset(0, 11).Value & r.Offset(0, 12).Value & r.Offset(0, 13).Value _
                Like "*" & s & "*" Then
               'arr(i, 0) = ws.Name
                arr(i, 0) = r.Value
                arr(i, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
                arr(i, 2) = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
                arr(i, 3) = r.Offset(0, 3).Value
                arr(i, 4) = r.Offset(0, 4).Value
                arr(i, 5) = r.Offset(0, 5).Value
                arr(i, 6) = r.Offset(0, 6).Value
                arr(i, 7) = r.Offset(0, 7).Value
                arr(i, 8) = r.Offset(0, 8).Value
                arr(i, 9) = r.Offset(0, 9).Value
                arr(i, 10) = r.Offset(0, 10).Value
                arr(i, 11) = r.Offset(0, 11).Value
                arr(i, 12) = r.Offset(0, 12).Value
                arr(i, 13) = r.Offset(0, 13).Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With
   End If
Next ws
With Sheets(1)
    .Range("a13").Resize(i, 14).Value = arr
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
End With
    Next ws
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to remove the `With Sheets(1)` that you have your sheet loop nested in. I don't know if this is causing issues, but since you are doing a sheet loop, it is not necessary. To bold you just need a `For Each` loop. Since this is a one line code, I don't think the `With` block is even useful here. Just use `ws.Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Font.Bold = True`

Comment: Why do you have that empty `OptionCompareText()` sub at the top?

Comment: The OptionCompare was left over from when I was going to have a search field and button instead of just retrieving the data. Needs to be removed.

Comment: @urdearboy - Not sure how I would remove the With Sheets(1) line as without it the data that is retrieved from across the other worksheets doesn't populate the 6th worksheet. I did try removing it to see what would happend and the 6th sheet did not populate. Sorry I am somewhat of a newbie in vba so not sure if there is a better way of writing that piece of code.